# Queues with random GUID being generated in RabbitMQ server

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

Queues with a random GUID are being generated comming from exchange 'celeryresults'.

This happened when I fired a task from the shell, using delay method, but I forgot to enter parameters of my original function in the arguments list of delay.

Error displayed in terminal where I run the celery worker:

```
[2015-02-20 18:42:48,547: ERROR/MainProcess] Task customers.tasks.sendmail_task[1a4daf49-81bf-4122-8dea-2ee76c2a2ff8] raised unexpected: TypeError('sendmail_task() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cod/workspace/envs/cod/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cod/workspace/envs/cod/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sendmail_task() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)
```

How do I stop random queues from being generated? Why won't these messages use the default queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between the **broker** (sends/receives messages) and **backend** (stores/fetches task results) in celery. It sounds like you are using RabbitMQ both as the message broker and the result backend.

When RabbitMQ is used as a result backend, celery creates one queue per task to temporarily keep track of the result. This is described in the [RabbitMQ Result Backend](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#rabbitmq-result-backend) section of the docs.

If you don't want this behavior then you should either turn it off using [CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#celery-ignore-result) or switch to one of the other backend implementations listed in the [Result Backend Settings](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#conf-result-backend).

Comment: Yes thats precisely what was happening, I was using RabbitMQ both as broker and backend. Thanks.

Comment: i have disabled the results
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
but still many GUID queues are forming