# Using rabbitmq as both a message broker and backend

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I have been working with `Celery` and reading about `rabbitmq` vs `redis` for the message broker and backend. I would like to use the `rabbitmq` backend because it sounds like it is better at guaranteeing that data is not lost.

I asked this question ([rabbitmq queues filling up with celery tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650684/rabbitmq-queues-filling-up-with-celery-tasks)) concerning the `rabbitmq` queues filling up with random GUID's in the `mnesia` folder. Another user pointed me to this question ([Queues with random GUID being generated in RabbitMQ server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630268/queues-with-random-guid-being-generated-in-rabbitmq-server))that is similar. They mentioned that I should not be using `rabbitmq` as my backend, only a message broker.

I would like to consolidate my stack and only use `rabbitmq` for the message broker and backend. Is there a way to prevent the queues from slowly filling up and eventually killing the application due to memory overload?

using `CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` does not seem to solve the issue.

I want to run some hardware calls in parallel. Here's the Celery task:

```
@app.task
def call_plc(sitename, ip_address):
    vals = pc.PLC_Comm().connect_to(sitename, ip_address)
    return vals
```

I create a bunch of these tasks and put them in a list. Once `all([t.ready() for t in task_list]` returns `True`, I move on.

Another task just sends an email:

```
@app.task
def send_asyncalarm(sitename, alarm_list, timestamp):
    my_an = an.Alarm_Notifier()
    my_an.send_alarm(sitename, alarm_list, timestamp)
    return
```

I may in the future confirm that the email has sent, but right now it's "fire and forget"

Comment: Can you clarify 'backend'? What are some tasks / resposibilities?

Comment: `Redis` saves to disk (although less frequently by default, you can configure it to save more often, read about persistence here [http://redis.io/topics/persistence]). I had also decided to go with `rabbitmq` as the backend + broker for a project (that involves fire & forget tasks) but switched quickly switched to `Redis` as I found it easier to work with.